# Auto Increment column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two columns `SALARY_CODE` and `FN_YEAR`
I want to generate table like below on the basis of `FN_YEAR` column:
If `FN_YEAR` value is `18-19` then `SALARY_CODE` will be `SAL/01-18-19` and next value of SALARY_CODE for `18-19` will be `SAL/02-18-19`

[image]

Please help me to write the SQL to perform the discussed task.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking, because your sample data is not legible.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output....

Comment: two column  fn_year and Sal_Code -if null then output-SAL/01-18-19 if current fn_year=18-19 then after that  it will increment like SAL/02-18-19,SAL/03-18-19 like that.if financial turn to 19-20 then it will be SAL/01-19-20,SAL/02-19-20 Like that...

Comment: Hello all,  I have updated the problem you can look into this now. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @intCount int=0;
DECLARE @CustomID nvarchar(16);
DECLARE @fn_year nvarchar(16)='19-20';

SELECT @intCount = Count(SALARY_CODE) FROM temptest WHERE FN_YEAR=@fn_year
IF(@intCount = 0)
BEGIN
    set @CustomID='SAL/1-'+ @fn_year
    insert into temptest values (@CustomID,@fn_year)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
        SET @CustomID= 'SAL/'+ CAST(@intCount+1 as nvarchar(16)) +'-'+@fn_year;
        insert into temptest values (@CustomID,@fn_year)
END
```

You can write function like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getSalaryCode(@fn_year NVARCHAR(16))  
RETURNS NVARCHAR(16)   
AS   
-- Returns the SALARY_CODE 
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @intCount int=0;
    DECLARE @CustomID nvarchar(16);

    SELECT @intCount = Count(SALARY_CODE) FROM temptest WHERE FN_YEAR=@fn_year
    IF(@intCount = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @CustomID='SAL/1-'+ @fn_year
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @CustomID= 'SAL/'+ CAST(@intCount+1 as nvarchar(16)) +'-'+@fn_year;
    END
    RETURN @CustomID;  
END;
```

Comment: Hi Divya, thanks for your help.can i convert below code as a function and pass Custom code like 'SAL'  and it returns same output from the current financial year?

Comment: Hello @SolomonBehera, Yes we can convert. I have updated the answer, Please mark it as a answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: ERROR...Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure getSalaryCode, Line 14
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT' within a function.

Comment: @SolomonBehera Remove insert query from this as you can't use a function to insert data into a base table. Functions return data. This is listed as the very first limitation in the documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and `concatenate` with the other column to get the desired result

```
with data as ( 
(select '18-19' FN_YEAR union all 
 select '18-19' union all 
 select '18-19' union all 
 select '19-20' union all 
 select '19-20' union all 
 select '20-21')   ) 
 select  FN_YEAR, 
        ('SAL/'+CAST((row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY FN_YEAR order by FN_YEAR)) AS VARCHAR(50))+'-'+FN_YEAR) 
        as SALARY_CODE from data
```

[**Check Demo Here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=842782a462578227bae34168b0946e29)

Answer (score 0):

Create a table (let's call it mnths) with 12 rows (assuming all months are required) and an index colum with numbers between 1 and 12, and another table for the required years.
then add rows from that table for each month and  year, like this:

Table name: mnths

Field name: mnt (values: 1-12)

Table name: years

Field name: yr (values: 18-30)

```
SELECT 'SAL/'+CAST(mnt as nvarchar(2))+'-'+
CAST(yr as nvarchar(2))+'-'+CAST(yr+1 as nvarchar(2)) as SALARY_CODE, 
CAST(yr as nvarchar(2))+'-'+CAST(yr+1 as nvarchar(2)) as FN_YEAR
FROM mnths cross join years
```

If you already have the data, you can validate it against those tables and add missing entries.

Answer (score 0):

Divya Agrawal answer is pretty good. But what i think you need is a **trigger** to fill those values automatically when you insert something on the table. The below procedure is a sample of how to pretty much do it. Id is your table primary key.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Salary_MyTable]
ON [dbo].[MyTable]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
@Id
SELECT @Id = INSERTED.Id FROM INSERTED
SELECT @fn_year= INSERTED.FN_YEAR FROM INSERTED
SELECT @intCount = Count(SALARY_CODE) FROM temptest WHERE FN_YEAR=@fn_year

UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] SET [SALARY_CODE]= 'SAL/' + CAST(@intCount+1 as nvarchar(16)) +'-'+@fn_year) WHERE @Id = Id

END
```

Comment: thanks for your help.can i convert below code as a function instead of the trigger  and pass Custom code like 'SAL'  and it returns same output from the current financial year?

Comment: @Antonios Katopodis, We can also use triggers but I think there is not much need to make triggers as only one column need update in this scenario. Thanks for your suggestion.